# How to catch pressing of Escape button in textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('.field').keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 27) alert(event.keyCode);
});
```

I need to catch "Escape" pressing and do some actions. But now it code does't work. I have tried to use this code:

```
$('.field').keypress(function(event) {
    alert(event.keyCode);
});
```

I was pressing by Escape button, but it didn't work (I haven't seen any alerts). Please, tell me, how can I fix it?

Comment: jQuery normalises the `keyCode` in the [`event.which` property](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/). It's not an answer and won't solve the problem but just a tip

Comment: @Esailija: Talk about learning something every day...I thought it was `keyCode` that jQuery normalized (from `which` as necessary), but the docs are clear it's the other way around. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `keydown` or `keyup` rather than `keypress`. `keypress` only fires for keystrokes that result in characters, which (by convention) <kbd>Esc</kbd> doesn't (even though some charsets, such as ASCII, do have a character called "escape").

For more about handling keystrokes in JavaScript: [*JavaScript Madness: Keyboard Events*](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html)